# Add div image over a form div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this basic form

```
<div class="card mb-5 card-central-responsive" style="min-height: 579px;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form #apkCreationForm="ngForm" class="mt-2" novalidate  (ngSubmit)="onSubmitApk()">
      <div role="alert" class="mb-&  ng-star-inserted" style="padding-bottom: .10rem" ng-reflect-ng-class="">
        <h4 class="alert-heading">{{ 'apk.product-description' | translate }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label class="form-group has-float-label">
            <input class="form-control" required ngModel #name="ngModel" name="name" [(ngModel)]="apkName"/>
            <span>{{ 'apk.name' | translate }}</span>
            <div *ngIf="!name.valid && apkCreationForm.submitted" class="invalid-tooltip">{{ 'apk.name-required' | translate }}!</div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label class="form-group has-float-label">
            <ng-select
              [items]="isFree"
              bindLabel="id"
              name="isFree"
              bindValue="id"
              [(ngModel)]="isFreeSelected">
            </ng-select>
            <span>{{ 'apk.is-free' | translate }}</span>
            <div *ngIf="!isFreeSelected && apkCreationForm.submitted" class="invalid-tooltip">{{ 'apk.isfree-required' | translate }}</div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
    </form >
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to add a div image on top of this form to have something like this:
[image]

I tried many solutions without success. Please how could I achieve this ?
I use ng-bootstrap in my app
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying Position absolute, you can align any object. I just wanted to show you the procedure you're going to do in a simple way.

```css
body {
  background-color: #121723;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.form-container {
  background-color: #252A39;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.image-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  background-color: #2E3446;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.bordered-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px dashed #121723;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-container">
    <!-- image-container -->
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="bordered-div">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- image-container end -->
    <div class="row no-gutters form-tab">
      <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-3">
        <h6 class="text-capitalize text-right">product details</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6 class="text-capitalize text-right">graphic assets</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6 class="text-capitalize text-right">categorization</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <!-- İnputs  -->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. Just a question, a part of the content of the div with class="form-input" is hidden by the c=image container. how do I make the two divs don't overlap?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Since you're using Bootstrap, you need to adjust the column sizes. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options . If you need more tweaks, you can use media query. You can set "image-container" "width" and "height" for each dimension or you can set the "inputs" width and height property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use about div's in css

```
position: absolute;
left: %10;
top: %10;
```

But when on the different pixels measurement, you should something css diversity.